# MongoDB Aggregate ObjectId inside Array of embedded Documents

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have seen a ton of question about the `$lookup` aggregator for arrays of ObjectIds but I can't seem to find anything about when the ObjectId is inside an array of embedded documents.

I have the follow document inside a mongodb database:

```
_id: ObjectId('...')
Alarms: [
  {
    Gateway: ObjectId('...')
    Port: 1
  },
  {
    Gateway: ObjectId('...')
    Port: 2
  }
]
```

I would like to have the following:

```
_id: ObjectId('...')
Alarms [
  {
    Gateway: ...(Gateway Object),
    Port: 1
  },
  {
    Gateway: ...(Gateway Object),
    Port: 2
  }
]
```

I have tried the following with no success:

```
$lookup: {
  from: 'Gateway',
  localField: 'Alarms.Gateway',
  foreignField: '_id',
  as: 'Alarms.Gateway'
}
```

But this gives me the following result:

```
_id: ObjectId('...')
Alarms [
  {
    Gateway: {
      ...(Gateway Object)
    }
    Port: 1
  }
]
```

Comment: What happens if  you've third object like `{
    Gateway: ObjectId('...'),
    Port: 3
  }` in `Alarms` that doesn't have a matching doc in `Gateway`? Do you still want to keep that in `Alarms` array as is in final result or remove that & keep only the objects that have matches?

Comment: Change `as: 'Alarms.Gateway'` into `as: 'Alarms'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below queries :

If you don't want the object which doesn't have match in `Gateway` collection exist in `Alarms` array in final result :

```
db.Alarms.aggregate([{ $unwind: '$Alarms' }, {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'Gateway',
        localField: 'Alarms.Gateway',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'Alarms.Gateway'
    }
}, { $match: { 'Alarms.Gateway': { $ne: [] } } },
{ $addFields: { 'Alarms.Gateway': { $arrayElemAt: ['$Alarms.Gateway', 0] } } },
{ $group: { _id: '$_id', Alarms: { $push: '$Alarms' } } }
])
```

Test : [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8el0PDpCeqW)

Otherwise, if you want all objects in `Alarms` array to be returned irrespective of whether there is a match in `Gateway` or not :

```
db.Alarms.aggregate([{ $unwind: '$Alarms' }, {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'Gateway',
        localField: 'Alarms.Gateway',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'Alarms.GatewayObj'
    }
}, { $addFields: { 'Alarms.Gateway': { $cond: [{ $ne: ['$Alarms.GatewayObj', []] }, { $arrayElemAt: ['$Alarms.GatewayObj', 0] }, '$Alarms.Gateway'] } } },
{ $project: { 'Alarms.GatewayObj': 0 } },
{ $group: { _id: '$_id', Alarms: { $push: '$Alarms' } } }
])
```

Test : [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BphEwXmn3C2)

Difference between two queries would be one will return below object in `Alarms` array *(Vs)* one don't.

```
{
    "Gateway": ObjectId("5e2b5425d02e05b6940de2fb"),
    "Port": 2
 }
```